# QGIS SAGA Raster Normalization not working

Tags: qgis, raster, error, saga

I am trying to normalize (from 0 to 1) a 300 MB TIF file in QGIS but I only receive the following error code:

```
The following layers were not created. [Path.sdat] See the 'Log Window' in the main QGIS window for more information about the algorithm execution.
```

Unfortunately, there is no more information available in the main protocol.

I also already used the search function but couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: "Rescale raster" worked for me. Thank you BERA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use

- Rescale raster
- Translate, with the -scale option